# how many equations required to solve $v = \exp(j \cdot 2\pi \cdot (a \cdot \cos(\phi) \cdot \sin(\theta) + b \cdot \sin(\phi)))$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

How many equations required to solve (find $\theta$ , $\phi$)  system of equations have form:
$$v = \exp(j \cdot 2\pi \cdot (a \cdot \cos(\phi) \cdot \sin(\theta) + b \cdot \sin(\phi)))$$
given a, and b are integer numbers, and v is a complex number?

I have tried to use two equations, this is my solution:
$$\sin(\phi) = \frac{a_1 \cdot \frac{\angle(v_2)+(2\pi m)}{2\pi} - a_2 \cdot \frac{\angle(v_1)+(2 \pi n)}{2\pi}}{a_1 \cdot b_2 - a_2 \cdot b_1}
$$
where $\angle(v_1)$ is the phase of $v_1$,
$$
\sin(\theta) = \frac{ \frac{\angle(v_1)+(2 \pi n)}{2\pi} - b_1 \cdot \sin(\phi)}{a_1 \cdot \cos(\phi)},
$$
so we have soulations from $m_1$ to $\frac{a_2+b_2}{\sqrt2}$, $n_1$ to $\frac{a_1+b_1}{\sqrt2}$, where $m_1$, and $n_2$ is minimum integer number to make solution exists.

**Is there a way to reduce the solution range with an increasing number of equations?**

Comment: Are you using $j$ for $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes

Comment: OK. You're using a few notations that math people usually don't use, e.g., $\angle (v2)+2\pi m$. Also, subscripts you write as , e.g., a1, look better as $a_1$, which is a_1 with a dollar sign preceding and following.